Airflow error code 9 after upgrading version
I had an Airflow instance hosted on Google Cloud Composer. The composer and airflow versions were rather old (composer-2.0.14-airflow-2.1.4) and I foolishly thought that upgrading to the newest version (composer-2.9.1-airflow-2.9.1) would go without too many hiccups. Turns out I was wrong, because now the main DAG gets to the ingestion step it always fails with INFO - Task exited with return code -9. I understand (and I can see from the monitoring) that there is a huge spike in CPU/RAM at that moment, and therefore the worker shuts off, but what I fail to understand is WHY this happens after an update where no lines of code have been changed.
I understand that "just assign more resources to the workflow" is probably a viable answer, but that still doesn't explain why it worked just fine before upgrading.
Is anyone aware of any changes since airflow-2.1.4 that could impact this in such a manner where initially there were enough resources and now there isn't, just by virtue of updating?
I have tried loading the snapshot I took in GCC but this doesn't rollback the version.
